# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema Web\conexion.php on line 17

Tags: php, mysql

Me sale indicado ese error , pero no logro hacer que funcione.
adjunto el codigo de conexion.php

```
class Conexion
{

    public function __construct($server, $nameBD , $user , $pass)
    {
        $con = mysql_connect($server, $user , $pass);


        if (!$con) {
            die("Error al conectar:".mysql_error());
        }


        $selBD = mysql_select_db($nameBD);

        if (!$selBD) {
            die("Error al seleccionar la BD:".mysql_error());
        }
    }



    public function ejecutar ($query){

        return mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, te recomiendo que leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga un titulo mas acorde.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cual seria la linea 17?
Fijate si tenes activadas las etiquetas <? en la configuración del php.ini, las short_tags.

Comment: Pues me doy cuenta que no, amigo

Comment: El código que muestras no tiene el error de `Unexpected if`... es posible que ese error esté en otro sitio, o que tengas dos archivos que se llaman igual, pero en carpetas distintas. El código de tu pregunta no adolece de ese error.

Comment: Muchas gracias,seguire revisando.

Comment: buenos dias desde latino america, al parecer tienes problemas con la base de detos, solo fijate que tengan el mismo nombre y tambien no olvides poner una key en la base de datos por si estas trabajado por crud

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
$selBD = mysql_select_db($nameBD);
```

Deberia ser:

```
$selBD = mysql_select_db($nameBD, $con);
```

Por cierto, las funciones mysql han sido depreciadas.  Deberias usar msqli mejor.

Comment: Ya intente con aquello, pero aun me sigue arrojando ese error.Y si estuve leyendo acerca de eso, me tocara cambiar, muchas gracias amigo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a mi problema fue hecha mas al tanteo , lo que  hice es borrar los archivos php de la carpeta del proyecto, luego pegarlos en una "nueva carpeta", reiniciar el servidor y listo.

Gracias a todos.